# How can I copy data from CSV into QuestDB using Python?

Tags: questdb

I'm using the psychopg2 module to make queries against QuestDB from Python. I have had some trouble using the [copy_from()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) cursor object to get CSV data into a table. What's the best way to get this into the database?

I'm trying the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import psycopg2
import os

conn = psycopg2.connect(user="admin",
                              password="quest",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="8812",
                              database="qdb")

cursor = conn.cursor()

dest_table = "eur_fr_bulk"
temp_dataframe = "./temp_dataframe.csv"

# input
df = pd.read_csv("./data/eur_fr.csv")
df.to_csv(temp_dataframe, index_label='id', header=False)

f = open(temp_dataframe, 'r')

cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.copy_from(f, dest_table)
    conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    os.remove(temp_dataframe)
    print("Error: %s" % error)
    conn.rollback()
    cursor.close()

cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `copy_from()` wrapper in psychopg2 is executing some SQL in the background that's not yet supported in QuestDB as of yet, specifically, it will run

```sql
COPY my_table FROM stdin WITH DELIMITER AS '    ' NULL AS '\\N'
```

The `DELIMITER` keyword is not yet implemented. As a workaround, you can either make the request via HTTP in python, which might be the most convenient:

```py
import requests

csv = {'data': ('my_table_import', open('./data/eur_fr.csv', 'r'))}
server = 'http://localhost:9000/imp'

response = requests.post(server, files=csv)
print(response.text)
```

or you can specify a copy directory in the `server.conf` file which allows loading CSV files. This is documented on the [COPY documentation page](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/copy/).